# Python PyQt6 ListWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, qwidget, python-3.10, pyqt6

I use list widget to store pytube stream objects
currently I add to the list the title of the object ( text only )
parallelly I add the full object to list ( playlist_yt )

Here is the add function

```
 def add_to_playlist(self):

        if self.playlist_check.isChecked():
            print("checked")
            yt = YouTube(url).streams.get_audio_only(subtype="mp4")
            try:
                playlist_yt.append(yt)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

            self.playlist_obj.addItem(yt.title)
```

I try to create delete button to delete the selected line from widget

```
  def remove_item_pl(self):
        try:
            current_item =  self.playlist_obj.currentItem()  
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        if self.playlist_check.isChecked():

            try:
                self.playlist_obj.removeItemWidget(current_item)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

How we achieve that ?

Comment: Your try-excepts are unnecessary and just make your code less readable and hide possible bugs. If you want to remove the current item then pytube is irrelevant, just do the following:   `current_item =  self.playlist_obj.currentItem()` `if current_item is not None:` `self.playlist_obj.takeItem(self.playlist_obj.row(current_item))`

Comment: Use try-except when necessary, if not better wrap your entire code in a try-except (sarcasm).

Comment: I use try-except to debug , so few extra been added ..  your solution works , thanks!

Comment: No, try-except is not for debugging. In debugging it is expected that many things will break in order to correct them, and not to hide them under the carpet since later they will explode breaking everything but silently so that in the end it will fail without knowing the cause.

Comment: Ok , what you suggest to debug specific places in the code ?
I use pycharm though it debug function makes issue ( not debugging sometimes ) 
I use try-except and then remove it ...

Comment: If you are going to use it like that then keep in mind that you have to check if the function throws an exception, in the case of the currentItem() method it doesn't throw any exceptions (Qt doesn't use exceptions unlike the other libraries) so the try-except around of that code is unnecessary, useless and only makes it more difficult to read. From the above I can recommend: Check the documentation and use the try-except for the exception that can throw that function.